# requests module in Python is giving me same page despite different URL's I am passing to it

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

**Hi!**

Could someone tell me why using `requests.get(url)` with different url's I am getting same page. Story is:
I am scraping webpage to see products by brands. Thus I am generating urls based on brand list in page (I am retrieving them with `xpath`).
For other pages it works, however for this one is not.
So I wander maybe there is kind of protection from scraping the page? As when I am pasting those generated urls in chrome - it gives me page with specific Brand products I need.However with `requests.get` I am ending up at same page.
Also- maybe you can share easy- to - grasp info how requests works? How it reaches page source?

Zillion thanks to contributors !

Comment: Help us help you - share your code.

Comment: hard to tell without code to test. Possible solutions: a) include headers in your `requests.get()`; b) the page probably dynamic so could see if there is an api to access to get the data or find it within `<script>` tags; c) use Selenium

Comment: Yes I am using Selenium now as workaround but want to understand why it happens :).